# AWS SDK S3- how to include credentials in putObject method

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Instaed of using this HTML form:

```
<form action="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" /><br />

   <input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
   <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256" />
   <input type="hidden"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="MY_CERDENTIALS" />
   <input type="hidden"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
   <input type="hidden"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20180817T040045Z" />

   <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='MY_POLICY' />
   <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="MY_SIGN" />
   File:
   <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
 </form>
```

I want to use ASW SDK method `putObject` in javascript. I managed to create this code:

```
AWS.config.update({
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com'),
    accessKeyId: 'MY_ID', // the app does not run on AWS, so I need credentials
    secretAccessKey: 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
    s3ForcePathStyle: true,

  });
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";

const params = {
  params:{
    Bucket: 'ballot-box',
  }
}


var bucket = new AWS.S3(params);


const requestParams = {
  Key: 'test.png',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  Body: file
}

bucket.putObject(requestParams,function(err,file){
  if(err)
    reject({error: err})
  else
    resolve({image: encode(file.Body)})
```

My problem now is that I have no idea where and how should I put the Policy, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X--Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, x-amz-server-side-encryption and X-Amz-Date.

**EDIT:**

CORS configuration of my bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving from [browser-based upload via POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) to JavaScript SDK, you don't need to supply Policy, X-Amz-Signature, X-Amz-Date, X--Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, or X-Amz-Date.

You may, if needed, supply x-amz-server-side-encryption and the way you do that is in the requestParams, via ServerSideEncryption: "AES256".

Comment: The problem is that I get the error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". I managed to fix that when downloading the file by adding "<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>" in CORS but for uploading I still get it. Check my original post for whole CORS conf.

Comment: Fix that by adding 
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>. Thank you